# Undefined reference to MD5 (from OpenSSL)

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography, md5

I got Code::Blocks and I built OpenSLL from source on windows. I included the header files (openssl\include) and the lib files (openssl\lib\libcrypto.lib, openssl\lib\libssl.lib). But when I build the application it get an error saying unidentified reference to MD5 (line 5: `MD5((unsigned char*)string, strlen(string), (unsigned char*)&digest);`
). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Code:

```
string DoMD5(string s){
    unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    char const *string = s.c_str();
        MD5((unsigned char*)string, strlen(string), (unsigned char*)&digest);

    char mdString[33];

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
         sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

   // printf("i: %s o: %s\n", string,mdString);
    return mdString;

}
```

I am using OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
I am using Code::Blocks as an IDE.

Comment: The signature of MD5 looks as follows `unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n, unsigned char *md);`, thus you should just pass `digest` and not `&digest`.

Do you include the right header file?

Comment: if `#include <openssl/md5.h>` is correct then yes. I passed `&digest` as `digest`. This didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you distinguish whether it is a compilation or linking issue?

Comment: It's a compilation issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you compile just the failing unit and add the resulting log?

Comment: I did, all the was outputted was `obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to 'MD5'|`